# Block google in app purchase

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I am searching for the solution to block google inapp purchase in applications which are started through my application.
I have one application which lists number of apps installed in the phone now if user opens any listed application from my app and want to perform any purchase, it should not allowed to do.
User can perform the purchase if he start application from default launcher.

Comment: AFAIK...I dont think that can be done.

Comment: but this has been done in most of the apps available on google play.Like kids place, zoodles!!

Comment: So you basically want to control other applications started from within yours? That shouldn't be possible.

Comment: but kids place did it man....they just close the play screen whenever any child starts.